# How to down-size a large image (1600x1200) so it fits most screens as a background?

Tags: javascript, css

I have an image that is 1600x1200

I would like to use it as the background image for my site. The image should be static, only the content should be scrollable.

This is what i have tried:

```
background-image: url('blog-baggrund2.jpg');
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-attachment: fixed;
background-size: cover;
```

The problem is `background-size: cover;` stretches it so that the whole image is not shown, and `background-size: contain;` minimizes it so that it does not fit the whole screen (at least in width - height is perfect)

My own screen resolution is 1600x900

jsFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/zJNLJ/4/

Notice all the "black" stuff from the bottom of the image is not shown.

Any suggestions?

Comment: throw it up on jsfiddle with the image. i think i know a solution

Comment: You don't mind the picture being distorted? (i.e. stretched more horizontally than vertically)? Then you can use `background-size: 100%, 100%`

Comment: @MrLister Whether he likes it or not, the picture will be either distorted, or not shown fully/not covering the whole screen.

Comment: @MrLister Its okay if it is a little disorted, as long as the whole image is shown more or less. I tried your suggestion, doesnt scale the image as supposed to: http://jsfiddle.net/zJNLJ/6/ - Edit: removing the comma seems to fix the problem

Comment: Yes, sorry, I had a erroneous comma in there. Dan's answer is correct.

Comment: Why not use a media query and serve up the right size image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/zJNLJ/5/

I changed the `background-size` to `100% 100%`

Comment: @Kenci you can put the image in an `<img>` element and then put the rest of your content in front of that.

Comment: you can try reading here: http://www.quackit.com/html/codes/html_stretch_background_image.cfm

Comment: oh and another option is to use javascript

Answer (score 0):

background-size property does what you want.
"background-size:cover;"    Scale the image to the smallest size such that both its width and its height can fit inside the content area

more @ http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp

Comment: BTW that jsfiddle worked perfectly in my browser (latest CHROME version at 15th august 2012). What's your browser version?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe edit the image to have an equal width/height and then set it to 100%? Might look best this way.